# Generate Javascript source map without adding NPM to project

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, source-maps

My web project serves static web pages and scripts. There is no preprocessing done at all. All changes are done in the client.

It has a main page that lists some other pages. When the user clicks a link, jQuery-UI will load the associated HTML page and any linked Javascript/CSS files.

This works great, and gives us flexibility to add/remove new pages with ease. The problem is when we want to debug the loaded JS and the browser appears not to know about it.

Took me a while to find out about Source Maps, and then find out they are all geared towards framework projects like Angular and React.

We don't want that in this project. Just basic HTML & JS that we can plug in and reload. I realize we may need to run an external command to generate the source maps, but it must be a free standing tool - no NPM or frameworks.

It's an internal web project, so security/privacy is not a concern. We *want* the clients to see the source code if they need to.

I know there are a lot of Questions about JS source maps, but every single one that I've found assumes using some framework tools. We have no framework and do not want one in this project.

**Any suggestions on how we can generate the source maps we need, or do you know of any alternative to debug simple JS loaded via jQuery?**

Comment: If you're loading un-pre-processed JavaScript directly, you don't need a sourcemap. A sourcemap is useful for minified scripts or for scripts originating from a cross-compiled language like TypeScript or ClojureScript.

Comment: I am NOT loading it directly. jQuery UI pulls it in as Tab content using Ajax. I even have to adjust the Script tag's *src* path to be relative to the location of the main page rather than the loaded page.

As a result, the browser loads it and runs it, but pretends it doesn't actually exist in the debugger.

Comment: Well, you could try loading via dynamically-created `<script>` tags instead. Otherwise it's very hard to get away from the Node/npm ecosystem to use a lot of contemporary tools like that.

Comment: For example, main page is at root /.
If a user is interested in pugs.html content, it may be loaded from /pets/dogs/pugs.html. That file has a <script src="/pets/dogs/pugs.html"> instead of <script src="./pugs.html">, even though the JS file is in the same place as the HTML.

Comment: Dynamic script tags won't work because each sub-page is solely aware of what it needs. Some may not have CSS or JS at all. As we add new pages, there could be a hundred different JS source files, and we only load them as needed.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what to do. This seems like an architectural issue, really, since there are conflicts between the way your application works, the way your build/development environment works, and the way browsers work.

Comment: The only conflicts are the fact the browsers can load and run a script but not let me debug it.

Everything else is as straightforward as can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, you do not need to use Angular/React for sourcemaps to work. These are just a common use case.

Secondly, NPM is exactly what it says it is; a package manager. So you don't *need* NPM either.

What you *need* is a build process. You're quite clear that you don't want to minify the js, but you do want sourcemaps. This is a common configuration used to debug js, and is typically accomplished by "building" or "Uglifying" the code with all of the optimizations disabled.

You could likely avoid NPM entirely if you were willing to use the Closure Compiler, but that is a can of worms and I'd suggest you avoid.

Instead I suggest using installing [Uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2)* globally* (per dev machine) *with* NPM. This is a "once per machine" step.

```
npm install uglify-js -g
```

*: Hopefully this side steps your NPM-less requirement. I did experiment with cloning the Uglify repo directly, but even then you'd need to get it running, and to do that, at a minimum, you'd want to install its dependencies with NPM). I'd love to be proven wrong about this, but I figured it was very unrelated to this post.

And then writing a build script using that. I've attempted to gather the parts for you here:

File: *gen-map.sh*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

uglifyjs file1.js --config-file gen-map.json \
  -o file1.min.js  \
  --source-map "root='http://foo.com/src',url='file1.min.js.map'"

cat file1.min.js
```

File: *gen-map.json*

```
{ 
  "compress": false,
  "output": {
    "beautify": true
  },
  "sourceMap": {
    "content": "content from file1.js.map",
    "url": "file1.js.map"
  }
}
```

File: *file1.js*

```
var b = function() {
  console.log('b');
};

function c() {
  console.log('c');
};

console.log('a');
b();
c();
(function() {
  console.log('d');
})();
```

File: *file1.min.js*

```
var b = function() {
    console.log("b");
};

function c() {
    console.log("c");
}

console.log("a");

b();

c();

(function() {
    console.log("d");
})();
//# sourceMappingURL=file1.min.js.map
```

File: *file1.min.js.map*

```
 {"version":3,"sources":["file1.js"],"names":["b","console","log","c"],"mappings":"AAAA,IAAIA,IAAI;IACNC,QAAQC,IAAI;;;AAGd,SAASC;IACPF,QAAQC,IAAI;;;AAGdD,QAAQC,IAAI;;AACZF;;AACAG;;CACA;IACEF,QAAQC,IAAI;EADd","sourceRoot":"http://foo.com/src"}
```

*: Uglify-es if you're using ES6 features.

After that the only thing left to do would be to update the paths, filenames, and actual script tags. Using this config you must still serve the min.js file, although it seems possible that [manually tagging](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-source-maps) your JS file to point to the map might work...

With this config, you'll need to keep your built files up to date by running:

./gen-map.sh

Doing this with npm and gulp would be simpler, but, if you don't mind another package, there are 2 generic "files been changed watchers" that I can suggest;

[Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon):

```
 nodemon gen-map.sh
```

[entr](http://entrproject.org/)

```
 entr gen-map.sh
```

Comment: Thanks! So sorry I missed this answer so long ago. Still relevant, however, and I'll try implementing it when I can. Great detail.